# Is it possible to change php bin/console via composer?

Tags: symfony, ubuntu, composer-php

I have tried to add

```
"scripts": {
    "sym": "php bin/console", 
    }
```

in composer.json and made `composer install` after that.

However if I run `sym make:migration` instead of `php bin/console make:migration` I have an error:

```
Command 'sym' not found, did you mean:

  command 'sem' from deb parallel
  command 'sm' from deb sm
  command 'vym' from deb vym
  command 'sys' from deb openafs-client
  command 'sum' from deb coreutils
  command 'syf' from deb alliance
  command 'spm' from deb salt-common
  command 'srm' from deb secure-delete
  command 'scm' from deb scm

Try: sudo apt install <deb name>
```

Did I make something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to prefix your command with `composer`. So `composer sym make:migration` will do the job with Composer.

To make your command work you don't need Composer. You have to create an executable. Create a file named `sym` in your project root:

```
#!/bin/sh
php bin/console $1
```

Make the file executable `chmod +x sym`.

`./sym make:migration` will work.

Comment: Thank you for wider a solution. You have helped me a lot!